# Как из адаптера открыть новую активити?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview.adapter

Получается код имеет следующий вид:

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Phone phone = phones.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
        holder.nameView.setText(phone.getName());
        holder.companyView.setText(phone.getCompany());
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("кликнул по: ", phone.getClickbutton());
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Соответственно

```java
startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
```

Не хочет тут работать.

Привожу полный код адаптера:

```java
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Phone> phones;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Phone phone = phones.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
        holder.nameView.setText(phone.getName());
        holder.companyView.setText(phone.getCompany());
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("кликнул по: ", phone.getClickbutton());
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return phones.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView nameView, companyView;
        final Button button;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            companyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.company);
            button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот собственно вопрос. Как мне открыть из адаптера новую активити... Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с того, что ваш адаптер и не должен уметь ее открывать. Адаптер должен уметь только показывать список ваших элементов. А клики обрабатывает View в которой находится адаптер.

Как это правильно сделать? Создайте свой интерфейс, что-то вроде такого:

```
interface ItemClickListener{

    onItemClick(data: YourData);
}
```

Реализуйте его в вашей View (Activity, Fragment или любая другая View). Сам интерфейс можно передать либо в конструктор адаптера, либо методом. Собстевнно при клике на ваш элемент вызывайте клик у вашего листенера. Тогда проблем с вызовом активити не будет и вы разделите ответственность.

Вот [тут](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/) есть хорошая статья на эту тему.

**UPD:**
Пример адаптера:

```
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final ItemClickListener listener;
    private final List<YourData> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public YourAdapter(ItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, null, false);
        return new ViewHolder(root);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void update(List<YourData> items){
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private Button buttonOne;
        private Button buttonTwo;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            buttonOne = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
            buttonTwo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_two);
        }

        void bind(YourData data, ItemClickListener listener){
            buttonOne.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onClickButtonOne(data));
            buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onClickButtonTwo(data));
        }
    }
}
```

В активити:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implementes ItemClickListener {

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(data: YourData){
        Intent intent = ...// Тут положите ваши данные в бандл, а бандл в интент
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно ли более детально увидеть код как это делается в моём случае и куда вставлять.. Спасибо .. Пишу на java только..

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Дальше уже только подставляйте свои параметры

Comment: Не могу разбораться( .. а как это будет выглядеть на моём коде? Что подставлять в setOnClickListener ?

Comment: setOnclickListener(v -> listener.onItemClick(data))

Comment: Не получается подключить.. А не могли бы вы на примере моего адаптера показать как это может выглядеть? Я понимаю уже нагло с моей стороны. Но если поможете буду крайне благодарен .. если нет то всё равно спасибо, буду сидеть разбираться..

Comment: holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              listener.onItemClick(//сюда вы кладете нужный параметр для передачи во View. Тут уже вы сами должны решить что вам надо чтоб открыть активити)
            }
        });

Comment: Да тут я и застрял, адаптер ItemClickListener - такого не находит .. всё сделал как по инструкции вашей. private final ItemClickListener listener; - не подключается

Answer (score 0):

Проблему помогли решить тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209329/how-to-open-a-new-activity-from-the-adapter
Всё оказалось как я и думал очень просто.

Добавил context:

```java
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Phone> phones;
private Context context;

public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Phone> phones) {
    this.context = context;
    this.phones = phones;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
// Remainder code
}
```

И изменил функцию:

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Phone phone = phones.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
    holder.nameView.setText(phone.getName());
    holder.companyView.setText(phone.getCompany());
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("click: ", phone.getClickbutton());
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Information.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Профит!

Comment: Это плохой подход, вы должны использовать либо интерфейсы, либо лямбды функции

Comment: а в чём плохой? какие последствия могут быть?

Comment: Вы нарушили один из принципов SOLID - принцип единой ответственности. Adapter служит для показа данных и ничего больше. Вы же ему добавили действие, за которое должно отвечать Fragment или Activity

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, почитал. Пока не такой я опытный чтобы их уметь соблюдать. Но буду стремиться